# GatsbyJS - Blog posts not loading on direct link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, gatsby

I've been playing with Gatsby for a while now and absolutely love it.

I did come across a little issue that I have no clue how to fix.

I'm rendering blogs posts from my markdown files.

Functionality of the site works fine when you start the site by visiting the homepage / root.
https://www.ronaldlangeveld.com/

However, I'm having issues with direct links to my blog posts.

I can access the blog posts by clicking on links from the homepage. However, when trying to access a specific page via direct link it only loads the header and not the post itself. Example https://www.ronaldlangeveld.com/deleting-facebook .

Here's my source code: https://github.com/ronaldlangeveld/gatsbysite

Anyone dealt with this before?

Cheers!

Comment: It's working fine actually.
I can see full blog post.

Comment: yeap. Found the bug minutes after posting this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @RonaldLangeveld I'm having the same issue. Would you mind answering your own question and accepting it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All I found was a 404 error before loading the service worker. After numerous attempts, the page is loaded without problems.

Apparently the problem is not GatsbyJS

[image: PrtScr]

Comment: Found the bug a few minutes after posting this. 
Thanks anyway