# page data not showing when directly navigating to page

Tags: gatsby

I have a problem with my gatsby site with graphcms where I can navigate my site just fine by clicking the various links in my site. For example, loading the landing page at `/` and then clicking a link to `/foo` loads the foo page just fine.

However, if I directly navigate to the `/foo` page in my url bar, none of the page's data shows. None of the data that is stored in `page-data.json` is showing in the browser.

Seems very similar to:

- [Gatsby - page refresh corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60118186/gatsby-page-refresh-corruption)
- [GatsbyJS - Blog posts not loading on direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234020/gatsbyjs-blog-posts-not-loading-on-direct-link)

```sh
$ yarn gatsby --version
yarn run v1.21.1
$ /home/vagrant/apps/agency-studio/ep/ep-website/node_modules/.bin/gatsby --version
Gatsby CLI version: 2.8.28
Gatsby version: 2.19.10
  Note: this is the Gatsby version for the site at: /home/vagrant/apps/agency-studio/ep/ep-website
Done in 0.71s.
```

**EDIT #1**

This doesn't happen on local (e.g. `$ yarn start`). It only happens when I host built files on s3.

**EDIT #2**

I can reproduce the problem with `$ yarn build && yarn serve`

Comment: That sounds like either you aren't copying everything into the public folder (or whatever folder has the build) or you are telling the server to serve the root instead of public. Compare the path in your dev and prod.

Comment: @DCTID thanks for the help. Regarding your suggestion to `compare the path in dev to prod`, forgive my ignorance, but how do you mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another dev on our team found the problem. There's a react bug (nothing gatsby related) issue with using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on `<p>` elements. Works fine with `<div>`'s though. Go figure...

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11108#issuecomment-455472204