# Page images and documents not loading on direct link

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have an issue with my images loading upon refreshing or directly going to a subpage. When navigating between pages via my header links the images load just fine but when I try to refresh the page the images all will not load.

The pages in question are here: https://wehab.stanford.edu/team and here: https://wehab.stanford.edu/research

Additionally, if you go directly to the Research page and try to click on any PDF link, the corresponding PDF will not load as well as the icon that goes along with it on the Research page.

I think this may have something to do with the way my path prefix is set up, as it is set to the root and not the public folder. (See: [page data not showing when directly navigating to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329374/page-data-not-showing-when-directly-navigating-to-page)). I have experienced problems with pathprefix before (see [Gatsby JS <Link> element in header navigation functional in localhost but not when generating static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64779260/gatsby-js-link-element-in-header-navigation-functional-in-localhost-but-not-wh))

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Relevant issues:

- [page data not showing when directly navigating to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329374/page-data-not-showing-when-directly-navigating-to-page)
- [Gatsby - page refresh corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60118186/gatsby-page-refresh-corruption)
- [GatsbyJS - Blog posts not loading on direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234020/gatsbyjs-blog-posts-not-loading-on-direct-link)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using path-relative links (they start with an alphanumeric character other than `/` and don't specify a scheme, hostname, or port), and when the page loads initially, the URL is `/team/`. This causes your image requests to go to paths like `https://wehab.stanford.edu/team/team-imgs/john-hegarty.png`, which subsequently 404:

[image: path relative links to images showing 404 errors in the developer console]

When you navigate client-side, the page is loaded at `/team` (no trailing slash), so the same image `src` paths resolve like `https://wehab.stanford.edu/team-imgs/john-hegarty.png` (no `/team` segment), which results in a 200 request with the image data.

To resolve the issue, you should probably change both the way you're referencing images to always be root relative (i.e. start with a forward slash) and be consistent about linking to pages with a trailing slash (or not). It may also be prudent to verify that the server itself is not returning a `Location` header inconsistent with your use of trailing slash paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `gatsby-remark-relative-images`, you need to have `trailingSlash` enabled in your Gatsby config. However, it is enabled by default, so you can just remove it from your config.

If not just use `gatsby-remark-relative-images`.